# Directory Looping Not Creating Sub directories Correctly

Tags: c#, console, directory, subdirectory

### Figured Question 1 Out. Please Refer to Question 2. Still need help there. Refer to my answer for Question 1 Solution

**This is a Console C# Based Program**

### Question 1

I want to Loop the Creation of a Directory Creation. I'm Using the Following Method to Duplicate a Directory (Please Ignore Using a Do While For Now... I just want the Device Numbering to be Correct and at the right Place). For now lets say we run the app each time manually. I want the Naming and Numbering of the List as Follows on each execution it should build a list as follows...

C:\\Some Location\\Devices

Within the Location...

- Device 1 Folder with Contents inside
- Device 2 Folder with Contents inside
- Device 3 Folder with Contents inside

And so forth... In other words i need some sort of loop to replace the naming of the device with the next index

This is the Method in Use...

- Path - Read in via the User. For Instance "D:\\" to duplicate The D:\\ Drive Contents
- True - Default for Copying the Sub directories as well and not just the intended directory

  ```
  DirectoryCopy(path, @"C:\\Custom Location to duplicate to", true);
  ```

Method Implementation :

```
private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(sourceDirName))
        {
            cancontinue = true;

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

            //Make an Array of Directories found on The Device
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

            if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }
            else
            {

                //Provide a Device Listing. Here is Where I am Stuck

                for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(destDirName)) 
                    {
                        destDirName = destDirName + "\\Device\\ " + i.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }
```

What follows is the Loop to Copy the Sub directories in the same manner. The Current Solution Provides the Following Output...

C:\Custom Location\Devices\Device 1\Contents

And within the Device 1 the Second Device will copy and within that the next and so on.

## Question 2

I want to Customise the Path it Copies to, to the Machine Name (For publishing Purposes)

```
    //This Gets the Name Perfectly + The Added Desired Path Below
    string MachineName = System.Environment.MachineName;
    string DesiredPath = "\\Desktop\\Program\\"; 

    DirectoryCopy(path, @"C:\Users\" + MachineName + DesiredPath, true);
```

Problem Here is that i get an Access Denied Error??? Why is that? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:

The for loop shouldn't overwrite destDirName variable:

```
private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(sourceDirName))
    {
        cancontinue = true;

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

        //Make an Array of Directories found on The Device
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }
        //Provide a Device Listing. Here is Where I am Stuck

        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            string tmp =  destDirName + "\\Device\\ " + i.ToString();
            if ( ! Directory.Exists(tmp)) 
            {
                 Directory.CreateDirectory(tmp);
                 // !!!
                 // here apply your function to copy 
                 // from sourceDirName to directory in tmp variable
                 break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question 2

I bet that you don't have rights to create directory in c:\Users\
Try to execute this as Administrator

Comment: That takes the Ability to use the program over and over away

Comment: why? In every DirectoryCopy call it will create directory Device with next number in destDirName directory. Then you have to copy content of source dir to it. Or I don't understand something...

Comment: Yes you copy The Entire Device Directory over to the new destination as a numbered device (Device 1, Device 2 Etc). That includes Its contents & Sub directories. In other Words if i plug a USB into the computer and execute the program, a Device 1 Should be created holding all the contents of the device of my choosing.(Already have the copying working). One i run the Program on the same or another device it should create a Device 2 witht he similar action

Comment: I edited answer to include whole function. Look for comments started with !!! and apply there your copying mechanism. I think it should work as you expect.

I'm not sure if this line: `destDirName + "\\Device\\ " + i.ToString();` creates directory name you expect, I copied it from your code snippet, so check it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i figured out what my problem was. Fixed it. 2 Things were wrong...

1. This first if must only contain a (Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);) otherwise it messes up sub directory naming
2. Secondly using the Directory Info I created an array to check 1st what my destination path held (What devices i already had Device 1 to infinity) then using a counter just added a new device enabling a device listing directory

   if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
               {
                   Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
               }

   ```
           else
           {
               DirectoryInfo dircheck = new DirectoryInfo(destDirName);
               DirectoryInfo[] dirscheck = dircheck.GetDirectories();

               //Start at Device 1
               int count = 1;

               Item presents each file in the Destination directory
               foreach (var item in dirscheck)
               {
                   //If the FileName (Lets say Device 1) contained the count which is 1 then increment... Do so until you reach the last index of a device.
                   if (item.Name.Contains(count.ToString()))
                   {
                       count++;
                   }
               }

               //Give the Destination directory the name of the last index of the count + 1
               destDirName = holdoriginal + "Device " + count + "\\";

               Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);

           }
   ```